# how to share data between modules in angular 7 in secured way?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have used concepts of Angular navigation for sharing data from one module to the next module.

Like I have a module A and a Module B. Here, module A has route /A and Module B has route /B, and my application firstly invokes module A and gets some data from rest API. After that, when it routes to module B, I need to use that data.**so now I have used angular navigation. like

```
this.router.navigate(['/B', {dataforB: JSON.stringify(A),
   userdata: JSON.stringify(A.user) }]);
```

It lets me some unfamiliar for data sharing. Sharing data this way is insecure, so are there any methods in angular, which let me handle data? I don't wanna use local storage and session storage.

Comment: you can check event emitter

Comment: You can use Redux framework (angular implementation ngRx) to share data among modules. Also you can use Shared Services

Comment: can you please share stackblitz link ?

Comment: as said by @rajiv you can use redux state management from https://ngrx.io/

Comment: if there is parent child relationship than you can use input and output

Comment: as the two components are not at time, you has different aproach: use a service (the services are maintain along the angular app life), use the property state, when make the navigation, see, e.g. https://netbasal.com/set-state-object-when-navigating-in-angular-7-2-b87c5b977bb, or store the data and use the params to get the values stores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngrx is a good approach for data sharing.